# Buckminster is throwing component not found and org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException Exception in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-rcp, buckminster

I am trying to build Eclipse Product with Buckminster.But when i do invoke action and select create.product.It showing me  Component "Plugin name" is not found in Buckminster and org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException.
How to solve these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Not trolling, but you should switch to Tycho, the underlying base of CBI ( http://wiki.eclipse.org/CBI )

Here are some resources:

- http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/documentation.php
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseTycho/article.html

Regards